# AdMob Mediation iOS: Is iAd or AdMob Ad Being Presented?

Tags: ios, admob, iad

Is there a programatic way to tell if AdMob mediation is presenting an iAd or AdMob ad?

The parent view to my GADBannerView has to do something special depending on which ad is being presented...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the `mediatedAdView` property on `GADBannerView` and see if it's of type `AdBannerView`.

Comment: If it is of type AdBannerView, does that mean it is an iAd (and not something else)?

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  Only problem is it was not the source of the issue I am experiencing I guess :(

Comment: Remember to #import <iAd/ADBannerView.h>